# What might be a good strategy in separating contents in paired parentheses using C

Tags: c, string, token

I would like to implement a C function that separate contents in paired parenthesis. The result is stored in a two-dimensional char array, with each row storing one token.
In C there is no regular expressions. So I would like to know what built-in functions can be used to realize it?

For example, if the input is `(* 5 10 (Expression1) 100 (Expression2))`, the result would be a char array with content of `*`, `5`, `10`, `(Expression1)`, `100` and `(Expresssion2)`.

Comment: @immibis it is `(Expression2)` I made the edit.

Comment: Is there some reason you can't just count the parentheses?

Comment: @PaulGriffiths No. How can I realize this implementation if I count parenthesis?

Comment: basically c is that, do it your self. it is harder but faster.

Comment: @JiajuShen: Increment a count when you see an opening parenthesis, decrement it when you see a closing. Whenever your count is 2, just keep on copying characters until it drops to 1.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths That is great. If you would like to write this as an answer I will upvote it.

Comment: Are you always guaranteed the your input will start with its first char `(` and last char `)` and all other `()` inside should be included in the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, following from the comment, then your parsing options are pretty much always the same. You either walk a pointer down the string, manually separating the tokens into an array, or you use the `strtok` or `strsep` functions. Below the example uses `strtok` to separate the string into `array` (a statically declared array of pointers) with a max of `64` pointers for tokens available (as defined with `#define MAXTOK 64` at the beginning).

A simple pointer `p` and `strlen` are used to skip the opening and closing `'()'` by starting the parse at the 2nd char and overwriting the last `')'` with a `null-terminating` character:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXTOK 64

int main (void) {

    char s[] = "(* 5 10 (Expression1) 100 (Expression2))";
    char *array[MAXTOK] = {NULL};
    char *p = s;
    size_t idx = 0;
    size_t len = 0;
    size_t i;

    len = strlen (s); 

    p++;            /* skip opening '(' */
    s[len-1] = 0;   /* skip closing ')' */

    /* parse remaining string into tokens stored in array */
    for (p = strtok (p, " "); p; p = strtok (NULL, " ")) {
        array[idx++] = strdup (p); /* allocate mem for tok, assign to array */

        if (idx == MAXTOK) {  /* check max number of pointers filled */
            fprintf (stderr, "warning: max tokens filled.\n");
            break; /* if you dynamically declare array, you can realloc */
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < idx; i++)
        printf (" array[%2zu] = %s\n", i, array[i]);

    /* free memory allocated by strdup */
    for (i = 0; i < idx; i++)
        free (array[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
$ ./bin/parse_expr
 array[ 0] = *
 array[ 1] = 5
 array[ 2] = 10
 array[ 3] = (Expression1)
 array[ 4] = 100
 array[ 5] = (Expression2)
```

This is a standard approach. Your other option is to dynamically declare `char **array;` and to allocate pointers with `calloc` (or `malloc`) initially and `realloc` when the limit is reached, as needed.

Comment: What if the `Expression1` and `Expression2` are something that is similar to our expression that is to be processed? If `Expression1` is `+ 5 10 (Expression3)` how can I keep it intact meanwhile process others?

Comment: Oh, that is something that will have to be added. Doable, but a direct simple `strtok` breaking on `space` will obviously not work there. Let me think on it. The initial comment on counting parens has value here. On the other hand, if `(Expression1)` can be expanding post-`strtok`, then it may be something that can be done in a secondary loop. Are there times when that is occurring, or are you saying you have previously declared `char Expression1[] = "+ 5 10 (Expression3)";`? It may also make more sense to parse the blocks that can be broken down with `strtok`  into separate strings.